# Add JRE to Maven project classpath

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I'm new to Maven and I ran into the following problem: I've created a sample Maven project and I'm trying to create some war. I've added several dependencies to my pom.xml, but I just can't figure it out how to add JRE to classpath. When I compile war module, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] /C:/path/to/class/PreferredMapper.java:[3,44] package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/path/to/class/PreferredMapper.java:[11,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class NamespacePrefixMapper
```

Class `NamespaceprefixMapper` is included in JRE's library `rt.jar`, so I'm guessing that my JRE is not in a compile classpath. I already tried to add JRE as a dependency im my pom.xml, but it's not working.

What is the correct way to add JRE libraries to a classpath?

EDIT1:

War module pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-module-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>war-module</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WarModule</name>
<description>WAR module</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.ws.admin</groupId>
        <artifactId>client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.ws.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>thinclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It's a multi-module project with ear and war module. I'm trying to install artifacts to my local repository by running `mvn install` command.

Comment: You're going to need to show us your pom.xml file, and possibly the command line you're using to generate the war.

Comment: @Goibniu see EDIT1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a properties section which would include the following (change the version as desired)

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Then add the compiler plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I think I've seen more elegant ways of doing it, but this is what I'm used to.